# List image paths - 'Namespace' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, image, parsing, path, argparse

I'm trying to return the image path, as follows:

```
from imutils import paths
import argparse

# create parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# define the command-line options
parser.add_argument('--dataset', required=True,help='path to the dataset')
# read the command-line arguments and interpret them
args = parser.parse_args()

imagePath = paths.list_images(args['dataset'])

print imagePath
```

But, getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    imagePath = paths.list_images(args['dataset'])
TypeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I ran the script by typing the following command:

```
$ python test.py --dataset /images
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `args` is a `argparse.Namespace` object, not a dictionary.  You want an attribute.  Do `print(args)` to get a clearer idea of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
imagePath = paths.list_images(args.dataset)
```

Or if you need dict for some reason:

```
imagePath = paths.list_images(args.__dict__['dataset'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. For the first statement, I get the following error: "File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    imagePath = paths.list_images(args.dataset)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dataset'"

Comment: For the second statement, I get the following error: " File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    imagePath = paths.list_images(args.__dict__['dataset'])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__' "

Comment: @Simplicity re: #1 - that's weird, what's the version of argparse? and you're sure you're not using vars in there cause in the initial problem report type of object reported was not dict but Namespace, re: #2 - from the error message it seems that you've put `.dict` while it should be `.__dict__`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get the program working (Notice `vars()`):

```
from imutils import paths
import argparse

# create parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# define the command-line options
parser.add_argument('--dataset', required=True,help='path to the dataset')
# read the command-line arguments and interpret them
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print args

imagePath = paths.list_images(args['dataset'])

for image in imagePath:
    print image
```